# Docker container volume not mounting

Tags: docker, mantis

I'm working with an mantis container : https://hub.docker.com/r/vimagick/mantisbt

On my linux instance I mounted an EFS volume in /mnt/TestMnt/ folder.

So I would like to mount my docker content files directly in my EFS share throught the mounted volume (TestMnt).
Problem is when I run docker run commandlet, container is running well (but in reality it doens't work :) ) without error message, and I've got no files appearing in the EFS share.
Any idea ?

Here is the command I ran : `docker run -v /mnt/TestMnt/:/var/www/html/ -d --name Mantis -p 85:80 vimagick/mantisbt:latest`

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Do you have /var/html/html folder inside that custom image of yours?
If not then add this line in the Dockerfile first and then build the image again:

> ADD . /path/inside/docker/container

You can also try this first, since this seems to be the better way and it works for me as well:

> docker run -it --mount src=/mnt/TestMnt/,target=/var/www/html/,type=bind k3_s3

Comment: If I execute command docker run without adding -v parameter, I can run command :
`docker exec -it Mantis /bin/bash`
And /var/www/html folder is automatically mapped and I can list files into html folder.

I tried your docker run -it.. command, but no errors, and no files readeable in the html folder if I enter into the container ... I don't understand..

Comment: docker run -it --mount src=/mnt/TestMnt/,target=/var/www/html/,type=bind k3_s3, this is how they've documented in their latest docs. Did you try it? Pretty sure it will work.

Comment: which image do you mean ? Mine ?

Comment: Yes, but first try the docker run command  which I have mentioned.

Comment: Here is the command I tried : ` docker run -it --mount src=/mnt/TestMnt/,target=/var/www/html/,type=bind --name Mantis -p 4481:80 vimagick/mantisbt:latest `

Where did you find the command in the doc, I didn't see it. do you have a link ?

Comment: And if I execute exactly your command result is container is starting but no files showing in the mount directory

Comment: I a reduce the path /var/www/html to /var only in my command, folders are created in the mounted volume, but no files created.

It's like Docker have no acl to write files